# unknow "query_string" error , while there is no query_string field in my table

Tags: laravel

error "query_string" not found, but it does not exist!?
My app works fine locally. When pushed to production I get an error when I add an to the table 'events'

```
[object] (PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'query_string' in 'field list' at /var/www/laravel/vendor/
```

and

```
Unknown column 'query_string' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `events` (`name`, `short_description, ....etc.
The strange thing is, there is no 'query_string' field in my database events:
```

The table structure is:

```
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                 | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description          | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| short_description    | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| picture              | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| event_start          | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| event_end            | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location_address     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location_description | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at           | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at           | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| team_id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.04 sec)
'''


This results in a 500 error, 

The error occurs only when the app is pushed to production.
On localhost, php artisan serve, and xampp,  everything works fine.
```

Comment: Can you show the query which is throwing the error?

Comment: can you update your question with controller and model also

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    function index(){
        $events = Event::paginate(15);
        
        return view('admin/events/index', ['page_title' => 'Admin Events', 'events' => $events]);
    }
    
    function create(){
        $event = new Event();
        
        return view('admin/events/edit', [
                'page_title' => 'Admin Events - Create',
                'submit_url' => 'create',
                'event' => $event,      
                'event_start_date' => '',
                'event_start_time' => '',
                'event_end_date' => '',
                'event_end_time' => '',
        ]);
    }
    
    function do_create(Request $request){
        
        
        return $this->save_event($request);
    }
    
    public function edit($id){
        $event = Event::find($id);
        
        $event_start = explode(" ", $event->event_start);
        $event_start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event_start[0]));
        $event_start_time = date('H:i', strtotime($event_start[1]));
        
        $event_end = explode(" ", $event->event_end);
        $event_end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event_end[0]));
        $event_end_time = date('H:i', strtotime($event_end[1]));
        
        return view('admin/events/edit', [
                'page_title' => 'Admin Events - Create',
                'submit_url' => 'edit/'.$id,
                'event' => $event,
                'event_start_date' => $event_start_date,
                'event_start_time' => $event_start_time,
                'event_end_date' => $event_end_date,
                'event_end_time' => $event_end_time
        ]);
    }
    
    public function do_edit(Request $request, $id){
        return $this->save_event($request, $id);
    }
    
    private function save_event($request, $id = null){
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'name' => 'required',
                'short_description' => 'required',
                'event_start_date' => 'required|date',
                'event_start_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
                'event_end_date' => 'required|date',
                'event_end_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i'
            ]
        );
        $request_all = $request->all();
        
        $event_start_time = strlen($request_all['event_start_time']) > 0 ? $request_all['event_start_time'] : "00";
        $event_end_time = strlen($request_all['event_end_time']) > 0 ? $request_all['event_end_time'] : "00";
         
        $request_all['event_start'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request_all['event_start_date']))." ".$event_start_time;
        $request_all['event_end'] = date('Y-m-d' ,strtotime($request_all['event_end_date']))." ".$event_end_time;
        
        if(isset($request_all['team_id'])){
           $request_all['team_id'] = intval($request_all['team_id']);
        }
        
        unset($request_all['id']);
        unset($request_all['_token']);
        unset($request_all['event_start_date']);
        unset($request_all['event_start_time']);
        unset($request_all['event_end_date']);
        unset($request_all['event_end_time']);
        
        if ($request->picture)
        {
            $this->validate($request, ['picture' => 'max:2000'], [__('Maximum file size of 2MB allowed')]);
            
            $image = $request->file('picture');//->store('pictures');

            $image_name = time().Str::random(5).'.png';
            
            if($id !== null){
                $event = Event::find($id);
                Storage::delete($event->picture);
            }
            
            
            $path = storage_path('app/public/Events/'.$image_name);
            //dd($path);
            $img = Image::make($image);
            $img->resize(300, 300, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($path);

            
            $request_all['picture'] = $image_name;
            
        }
        
        if($id === null){
            Event::create($request_all);
        }else{
            Event::where('id', '=', $id)->update($request_all);
        }
        
        return redirect('admin/events');
    }
    
    public function delete($id){
        if(empty($id)){
            return back();
        }
        
        $event = Event::find($id);
        
        Storage::delete($event->picture);
        
        $event->delete();
        
        return redirect('admin/events');
    }
```

and model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    function formatDateTimeList($time){
        return date('H:i d-m-Y', strtotime($time));
    }   
}
```

I also ran:

```
dd($request_all);
```

output when ran locally:

```
array:9 [▼
  "name" => "bnbnbn"
  "team_id" => 0
  "short_description" => "bnbnbnbn"
  "description" => "bnbnbnbnbnbn"
  "location_address" => "kakkakka"
  "location_description" => ".lkjhjlhg"
  "picture" => "1626178178U1Mct.png"
  "event_start" => "2021-01-01 00:00"
  "event_end" => "2022-01-01 00:00"
]
```

and this is the reaction when I push the exact same code to the server:

```
^ array:9 [▼
  "name" => "kdkjdkd"
  "short_description" => "kkkke"
  "description" => "jggogogoug"
  "location_address" => "kkkkmm"
  "location_description" => "mmmmm"
  "query_string" => ""
  "picture" => "1626178373BBarf.png"
  "event_start" => "2020-01-01 00:00"
  "event_end" => "2022-01-01 00:00"
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not sending `query_string` from your views ?

Comment: I searched for "query_string" in my project. It occurs nowhere in the entire  code..

Comment: thats strange. Can you try to dd($request->except('query_string'));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in this issue :-)

Locally

```
dd($request->except('query_string'));
```

returns:

```
array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "f3mcXT5TULG4vcTUPA8FEldgW4cIxt7wKfpN7jY7"
  "name" => "bnbnbn"
  "team_id" => "0"
  "short_description" => "bnbnbnbn"
  "description" => "bnbnbnbnbnbn"
  "event_start_date" => "2021-01-01"
  "event_start_time" => "00:00"
  "event_end_date" => "2022-01-01"
  "event_end_time" => "00:00"
  "location_address" => "klaverland"
  "location_description" => "klaverland"
  "picture" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1389 ▶}
]
```

when pushed to the server:

```
^ array:11 [▼
  "_token" => "pR0NOCDiUhFE9eZ9jLnffJPxPdlndnJUXB6WocUb"
  "name" => "okpoppp"
  "short_description" => "opkkopopk"
  "description" => "pookpkop"
  "event_start_date" => "2000-01-01"
  "event_start_time" => "00:00"
  "event_end_date" => "2022-02-02"
  "event_end_time" => "00:00"
  "location_address" => "sdjdjdj"
  "location_description" => "JJJ"
  "picture" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1318 ▶}
]
```

Comment: Okay so everything come as expected right ? Change the variable `$request_all` content from `$request->all()` to `$request->except('query_string');` and that's must do

Comment: ah, that is a workaround, for a strange problem...
Any idea what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Based on the information that is given, I don't have a clue. But somewhere there is given this `query_string` that is trying to be inserted on database, while it doesnt exist as a column. Can you show your blade file real quick too, including routes ?

Answer (score 0):

edit blade:

```
@extends('layout_admin')

@section('header')
    @include('includes.admin_header')
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="container minigame-container">
        @if(!$errors->isEmpty())
        <div id="card-alert" class="card orange">
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
               </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endif
        <form action="{{ url('admin/events/'.$submit_url) }}" id="event_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center m-2">
                    <h4><b> Event beschrijving</b></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col-6">
                    <label for="name">Naam</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col-6">
                    <input placeholder="Naam" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate" value="{{ old('name', $event->name) }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"> 
                @if(App\Settings::getStringSetting('teams_active'))
                    <div class="input-field col-6">
                        <label for="name">Teamnummer <br> (0 = geen team)</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col-6">   
                        <input placeholder="Team" id="team_id" name="team_id" type="text" class="validate" value="{{ old('team_id', $event->team_id) }}">
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="input-field col-6">
                    <label for="short_description">Korte beschrijving</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col-6">  
                    <input placeholder="Korte beschrijving" id="short_description" name="short_description" type="text" class="validate" length="128" value="{{ old('short_description', $event->short_description) }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col-6">
                    <label for="description">Beschrijving</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col-6">  
                    <textarea id="description" name="description" class="materialize-textarea">{{ old('description', $event->description) }}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 ">
                    Afbeelding
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 text-start ">
                    <div class="btn">
                        <input type="file" name="picture" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" style="display:none" />
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @if( $event->picture )
                    <div class="col ">
                        <img src="{{ url('images/event/'.$event->id) }}" style="height:150px"/>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label>Start datum/tijd </label>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-3">
                    <input type="date" id="event_start_date" name="event_start_date" class="datepicker" value="{{ old('event_start_date',$event_start_date) }}"/>
<!--                    <label for="event_start_date">Start datum</label> -->
                </div>
                <div class=" col-2"></div>
                <div class=" col-3">
                    <input type="time" id="event_start_time" name="event_start_time" value="{{ old('event_start_time',$event_start_time) }}"/>
<!--                    <label for="event_start_time">Start tijd</label> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col text-center">
                    Voorbeeld datum format: <b>16-05-2017</b>
                    <br><br>
                </div>      
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-4">
                    <label>Eind datum</label>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-3">
                    <input type="date" id="event_end_date" name="event_end_date" class="datepicker" value="{{ old('event_end_date',$event_end_date) }}"/>
<!--                    <label for="event_end_date">Eind datum</label> -->
                </div>
                <div class=" col-2"></div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <input type="time" id="event_end_time" name="event_end_time" value="{{ old('event_end_time',$event_end_time) }}"/>
                    <br><br>
<!--                    <label for="event_end_time">Eind tijd</label> -->
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label for="location_address">Adres</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input placeholder="Adres" id="location_address" name="location_address" type="text" class="validate" value="{{ old('location_address',$event->location_address) }}" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6"> 
                    <label for="location_description">Adres beschrijving</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">     
                    <input placeholder="Adres beschrijving" id="location_description" name="location_description" type="text" class="validate" length="255" value="{{ old('location_description',$event->location_description) }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-3" style="width:150px" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@stop
```

routes:

```
    Route::get('events', 'EventController@index');
        Route::get('events/create', 'EventController@create');
        Route::post('events/create', 'EventController@do_create');
        Route::get('events/edit/{id}', 'EventController@edit');
        Route::post('events/edit/{id}', 'EventController@do_edit');
        Route::get('events/delete/{id}', 'EventController@delete');
        Route::get('events/send_mail/{id}', 'EventController@sendMail');
```

Comment: Sorry, i cannot seem to find a solution to that, beside the one i gave you. Please try to use that if it works.

Comment: it works, thanks. Can I set your answer as best answer somewhere?

Comment: I answered above, you can mark it as answered if you'd like :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the $request_all from:

```
$request_all = $request->all();
```

to

```
$request_all = $request->except('query_string');
```